# Query Filter Sprecial Character (+) in Salesforce

Tags: apex, soql

I have a account 'H+S Aviat'.
I am trying below query getting correct result. `SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%H+S%'` but when I am querying it like this `SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%H+S Av%'`, no result is being returned (zero result). Please let me know whats the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Got it
It was a problem of extra space.
It is '`H+S  Aviat`'.